# What are the major differences between snapshot, dump, mirror, backup, archive, and checkpoint?

Tags: database, storage

I am new to the [SDDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_data_center) (software-defined data center), and I found these concepts over the Internet are at most vague.
Particularly, the last three concepts differ trivially, and to make things worse, people sometimes use them interchangeably. What are their major differences? I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62631147/what-is-the-difference-between-dump-download-snapshot-and-backup) but the explanation seems still not enough to answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Archiving** is the process of moving data that is no longer
   actively used as a separate storage device for long-term retention.
2. **Dumping** is a major output of data that can help users either back up or duplicate a database.
3. **Mirroring** refers to the real-time operation of copying data, as an exact copy, from one location to a local or remote storage medium.
4. **Snapshotting** is the state of a system at a particular point in time.
5. **Backup** is a copy of computer data taken and stored elsewhere so that it may be used to restore the original after a data loss event.
6. **Checkpoint** is a test operation that verifies data retrieved from the database by comparing that data with the baseline copy stored in your project.